# Mysql Error ERROR 2002 (HY000) persists after full reinstall

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

So I've been working on a rails server with MySQL and suddenly can't access my database. When I try to log in with `mysql -u root -p` I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. I've read most of the forums I can find and looked through all the logs trying to reset mysqld.sock. I've tried reinstalling and repackaging unsuccessfully. The weird thing is that var/run/mysqld/ doesn't even exist after reinstalling.

So I decided to just back up my databases and overhaul everything. I cleaned out both apache and mysql with apt-get remove --purge and reinstalled. All went fine, apache launched fine, and then tried to relaunch mysql with `systemctl start mysql` which gave a prompt to check the log which says:

```
  ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-12-16 23:56:19 UTC; 17s ago
  Process: 15690 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 16 23:56:19 ip-172-31-0-55 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Update - I created the folder mysqld, which seems to allow `sudo mysqld --initialize` to run. Unfortunately this yielded the error 
`2016-12-17T00:16:36.298825Z 0 [ERROR] Can't change data directory owner to mysql
2016-12-17T00:16:36.299212Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting`

So no party yet. Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not server or database administration. Try dba.SE.

Answer (score 1):

edit `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` :

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

add this line :
`socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

then restart mysql service :

```
sudo service mysql restart
```